# web config clear

Tags: asp.net, web-config

What is the use of the `<clear/>` in the web.config file?

I have it under connectionStrings:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <clear />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It clears all inherited keys, that's it.

Here is the MSDN Article: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903345(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: When will i have inherited keys?

Comment: When you're in a folder other than root. All the keys in parent folder will be inherited.

Comment: It also can inherit from the machine.config.