# MiniProfiler and WebForms

Tags: webforms, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

So I'm trying to use MiniProfiler (https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) for WebForms website. What I did is:

1. install package using nuget
2. add MiniProfiler initialization in Global.asax.cs (Begin_request and End_request events)
3. add <%= StackExchange.Profiling.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %> statement
4. set  at web.comfig

And still MiniProfiler doesn't work. Simple troubleshooting shows that (in Chrome dev tools) on that page I expect to see MiniProfiler, I see

http://localhost/mycoolsite/mini-profiler-resources/results 404.0 - Not Found

More info: I use .Net FW 4.5.1, IIS8 and Intergated Mode (app pool)

Any Ideas what may be useful for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've (very!) recently blogged about this, specifically [the process of getting MiniProfiler working in a hybrid WebForms/MVC application](http://robertwray.co.uk/blog/using-miniprofiler-with-a-hybrid-asp-net-web-forms-mvc-application-part-1).

Based on the steps that you've outlined that you carried out, it looks like you're missing (as compared to what I've got):

```
<%= StackExchange.Profiling.ClientTimingHelper.InitScript %>
```

That said, even without that line I still see *server side* timings and the MiniProfiler UI so I suspect that your `web.config` entry was/is incorrect.

Check to make sure that you've put this in `configuration` > `system.webServer` > `handlers` within your `web.config`:

```
<add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

There are a couple of other things that you can check as well:

1. Does the page that you're viewing live in a sub-folder that has a `web.config` either in it, or in a folder between it and the one where you added the `handlers` entry which [`<clear />s` handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626440/web-config-clear)?
2. Do you have anything else present in your application that could be capturing the request for MiniProfiler resources and returning a 404?